# How do I banish the "You have just inserted an Audio CD." dialog forever?

Tags: 10.04, nautilus, cd, autostart

Sometimes when I insert an audio CD I get a dialog that says "You have just inserted an Audio CD. Choose what application to launch." It doesn't show up for *every* CD... probably something like once for every 5 CD insertions.

*Every single time* I select "Do Nothing" and ensure that the "Always perform this action" checkbox is checked. I assume the point of the checkbox is to let me make the decision once and for all, but this dialog continues to reappear periodically.

Comment: And as if to taunt me, now when the dialog appears "Do Nothing" is selected and "Always perform this action" is already checked! Where's the "What part of 'Always' don't you understand?" button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prompting for action to perform upon inserting media is a behaviour of nautilus (the file browser program in GNOME Environment). To change this behaviour I would recommend the following steps:

1. Close all open `File Browser` windows
2. Open `Places -> Home Folder`. This will open the home folder in a new `File Browser` window.
3. Click `Edit -> Preferences`
4. Select the `Media` tab
5. For those media types where you don't want any prompt, select `Do Nothing` in the drop-down list.
6. Click `Close`

From next time, you should not get the messages while inserting media.

Comment: I went there and "Do Nothing" was already selected for CD Audio, DVD Video, Music Player, Photos and "Other Media/audio DVD".

Comment: ... and you still get this dialog once in a while ?

Comment: I haven't tested (yet), but why would opening a settings dialog and then dismissing it without changing anything cause the behavior to change?

Comment: Strangely, I have not seen the dialog appear again. That opening a settings dialog and then dismissing it without changing anything would actually alter the behavior seems like a bug, but at least it appears to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW: I filed a bug about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/665297

Answer (score 1):

In 12.04 this functionality is no longer in Nautilus and has been moved to the **System Settings application**.

Unity Dash -> System Settings -> System -> Details -> Removable Media

There is a checkbox there that says *"Never prompt or start programs on media insertion"* 

I haven't tested if it actually works though ;-)