# How do I change what happens after I insert an audio CD?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, cd-drive

Long ago I told Ubuntu to always open Banshee whenever I inserted an audio CD, but that behavior has gotten rather annoying as I am in the process of archiving my entire CD collection.  I would like to change the behavior to "Do Nothing".

I followed the instructions in the answer to this question: [How do I banish the "You have just inserted an Audio CD." dialog forever?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6677/how-do-i-banish-the-you-have-just-inserted-an-audio-cd-dialog-forever), but the Preferences -> Media tab is nowhere to be seen.

How do I accomplish this for Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open your system settings.

[image: System Settings]

- Click on Details.

[image: Details]

- Click on Removable Media.

[image: Removable Media]

- Select the Audio CD dropdown menu, and select "Do Nothing."

[image: Do Nothing]

Alternatively, you can disable "autorun" for all removable media by checking the box that looks like this:

[image: Never]

I'm using 12.10, but I remember 12.04 having the same procedure.