# How do I recall the "You have just entered a DVD" prompt after banishing it?

Tags: dvd, autoplay

My question is nearly an inverse of this one:  [How do I banish the "You have just inserted an Audio CD." dialog forever?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6677/how-do-i-banish-the-you-have-just-inserted-an-audio-cd-dialog-forever)

A long time ago, I selected "Do Nothing" and checked "Always perform this action", but now I have changed my mind and would like Totem to open when I insert a DVD.

If I recall correctly, this setting used to be in the Nautilus preferences, and later in the System Settings, but I have no idea where it is now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do.

1. Click the gear on the top left
2. Click "About this computer"
3. Click "Removable Media"
4. That's it! Enjoy!

Comment: Not seeing 'Removable Media' on 12.04..

Comment: Sorry. Try searching for "removable media" in dash.